# Laravel chunk method returning bool instead of data

Tags: php, laravel

I'm working with a Laravel 8 application and am trying to chunk a large set of data to reduce memory usage, however when I chunk my results and output my data I'm getting an empty array.

```php
$someHistory = [];
$history = DB::table('data_profiler_agents')
             ->whereDate('created_at', '>=', Carbon::now()->subDays(30))
             ->whereDate('created_at', '<=', Carbon::now())
             ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
             ->chunk(1000, function ($agents) use ($someHistory) {
               array_push($someHistory, $agents->toArray());
             });
```

What am I missing?

I just need to return all my data in the same format as a `->get()`, expect, chunk first.

I did try:

```php
$someHistory = $history->flatten();
```

and

```php
$someHistory = collect($history);
```

Neither of which seemed to work for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try passing `$someHistory` variable by reference to your chunk method. `&$someHistory`

```
$history = DB::table('data_profiler_agents')
             ->whereDate('created_at', '>=', Carbon::now()->subDays(30))
             ->whereDate('created_at', '<=', Carbon::now())
             ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
             ->chunk(1000, function ($agents) use (&$someHistory) {
               array_push($someHistory, $agents->toArray());
             });
```

Comment: That's solved it! Thanks for that, I knew it was relatively simple